# java.lang.StackOverflowError when doing a Spark TrainValidationSplit fitting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I tried to look for this issue on a lot of other posts but couldn't find a solution thus opening this one.

I'm trying to use the Spark [TrainValidationSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#train-validation-split) for hyper parameter tuning of my model.

I launch my code in standalone local mode on a 16Gb, 8cores PC with the following configuration in `spark-defaults.conf` : `spark.driver.memory 14g`. This is the only configuration I do.

I launch the fitting with a Gradient Boosted Tree classifier like this:

```
tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=classifier,
                           estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                           evaluator=evaluator,
                           trainRatio=0.8,
                           parallelism=4)
model = tvs.fit(training)
```

And I get a very long stack Trace error (25000 lines!) with no helpful information  which looks like this and seems to repeat itself:

```
16:55:57 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 101611,5,main]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2331)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1067, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
...
```

When I train other model such as Random Forest, it works. So I'm guessing it is because I got more hyperparameters combinations to test in TrainValidationSplit for GBT (36) than RF (4), as the lists used to build the paramgrid show:

```
RF_MAX_DEPTH = [5, 7]
RF_MAX_BINS = [32]
RF_NUM_TREES = [10, 5]
RF_IMPURITY = ['entropy']
RF_FEATURE_SUBSET_STRATEGY = ['auto']
RF_MIN_INSTANCES_PER_NODE = [1]
RF_MIN_INFO_GAIN = [0.0]
RF_SUBSAMPLING_RATE = [0.8]
RF_MAX_MEMORY_IN_MB = [8192]
RF_CACHE_NODE_IDS = [False]

GBT_MAX_DEPTH = [5, 7, 15, 20]
GBT_MAX_BINS = [32]
GBT_MAX_ITER = [200, 300, 1000]
GBT_STEP_SIZE = [0.05, 0.03, 0.2]
GBT_LOSS_TYPE = ['logistic']
GBT_MIN_INSTANCES_PER_NODE = [1]
GBT_MIN_INFO_GAIN = [0.0]
GBT_SUBSAMPLING_RATE = [0.8]
GBT_MAX_MEMORY_IN_MB = [8192]
GBT_CACHE_NODE_IDS = [True]
```

Why is TrainValidationSplit throwing this error and how can I solved it (other than remove some hyperparameters possibilities) ?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**EDIT**: I removed some hyperparameters possibilities (so there is only one possible combination) and it works. So the issue is there, but I really want to make it works.

**EDIT 2**: I have tried to add `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:ThreadStackSize=81920` as it is maybe probably related to jvm settings (as it a Java StackOverflow error) but it only made it crash later.